# Can vm-bhyve migrate a cloned vm?

Tags: freebsd, zfs, bhyve

I am trying to migrate (copy) a *bhyve* vm from one host to another using *vm-bhyve*'s migrate command.  If I migrate a zfs origin vm then the migration works.  If I try to migrate a clone of that vm then the migration fails.

Source host:

```
# freebsd-version -k -r ; uname -a
13.1-RELEASE-p6
13.1-RELEASE-p6
FreeBSD vhost03.hamilton.harte-lyne.ca 13.1-RELEASE-p6 FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE-p6 GENERIC amd64
```

Target host:

```
# freebsd-version -k -r ; uname -a
12.4-RELEASE-p3
12.4-RELEASE-p3
FreeBSD vhost01.hamilton.harte-lyne.ca 12.4-RELEASE-p3 FreeBSD 12.4-RELEASE-p3 GENERIC  amd64
```

vm-bhyve-1.5.0 on both systems

```
[root@vhost03 ~ (master)]# vm migrate -r vhp3ktest vhp3k101 vhost01
Attempting to send vhp3k101 to vhost01
  * remote dataset zroot/vm/vhp3ktest
  * stage 1: taking snapshot 20230628123722-s1
  * stage 1: sending zroot/vm/vhp3k101@20230628123722-s1
!!Warning!! -   Any deliberate attempt to access this resource without
                legitimate authorization is a criminal offence
                (R.S.C. 1985, c. C-46 - Section 342.1).
  * stage 1: snapshot sent
  * stage 2: guest powered off
!!Warning!! -   Any deliberate attempt to access this resource without
                legitimate authorization is a criminal offence
                (R.S.C. 1985, c. C-46 - Section 342.1).
  * renaming configuration file to vhp3ktest.conf
  * removing snapshots
  * done


[root@vhost03 ~ (master)]# vm migrate -r vhp3ktest2 vhp3k101rl88 vhost01
Attempting to send vhp3k101rl88 to vhost01
  * remote dataset zroot/vm/vhp3ktest
  * source guest is powered on (#75112)
  * stage 1: taking snapshot 20230628142653-s1
  * stage 1: sending zroot/vm/vhp3k101rl88@20230628142653-s1
!!Warning!! -   Any deliberate attempt to access this resource without
                legitimate authorization is a criminal offence
                (R.S.C. 1985, c. C-46 - Section 342.1).
cannot receive: local origin for clone zroot/vm/vhp3ktest@2023-06-03_02.00.00--6w does not exist
warning: cannot send 'zroot/vm/vhp3k101rl88/disk0@2023-06-03_02.00.00--6w': signal received
warning: cannot send 'zroot/vm/vhp3k101rl88/disk0@2023-06-04_01.00.00--3m': Broken pipe
warning: cannot send 'zroot/vm/vhp3k101rl88/disk0@2023-06-04_02.00.00--6w': Broken pipe
. . .
warning: cannot send 'zroot/vm/vhp3k101rl88/disk0@20230628142653-s1': Broken pipe
warning: cannot send 'zroot/vm/vhp3k101rl88/disk0@20230628143340-s1': Broken pipe
  ! error detected while sending snapshot
```

Is there some limitation which prevents *vm-bhyve* from successfully migrating a cloned vm or do I have some other problem?